# Binding element's background color to a slider in another window

Tags: wpf

I have an Avalon editor, whose background color I want to bind to a slider in a different settings window. I only want to change background color from black to white. Here is the code.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="JsonEditor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JsonEditor"
    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:JsonEditor" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="EditorMain"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="659" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    <Converters:BrushConverter x:Key="brushConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Background="Black">
            <Menu Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="File">
                    <MenuItem Header="Open" Click="MenuItem_Click_Load"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Save" Click="MenuItem_Click_Save"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Settings">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="Json_editor_toggle" Header="Show schema editor" IsCheckable="True" Checked="MenuItem_Checked" Unchecked="MenuItem_Unchecked" IsChecked="{Binding Visibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=stackPanel}"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="Validate_on_save_toggle" Header="Validate on save" IsChecked="{Binding ValidateOnSave}" IsCheckable="True"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="More settings" Click="ShowSettings"/>
                </MenuItem>
                
            </Menu>
            <avalonEdit:TextEditor x:Name="Text_Area" xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"
                   FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="10pt" Margin="0,0,0,10" ShowLineNumbers="True"/>

            <StackPanel x:Name="Json_Schema_Area">
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center">JSON schema:</TextBlock>
                <avalonEdit:TextEditor x:Name="Json_Schema" xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit" FontFamily="Consolas" 
                                   FontSize="10pt" Margin="10,0,10,0" Background="{Binding Blackness, Converter={StaticResource brushConverter}}"/>
                <Button x:Name="ValidateButton" Content="Validate" Click="ValidateButton_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace JsonEditor
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    
    private string lastFilePath;
    private ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = ViewModel;

        TextEditor textEditor=FindName("Text_Area") as TextEditor;
        textEditor.TextArea.TextEntered += OnTextEntered;
        //set line number color
        SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0,0,0));
        textEditor.LineNumbersForeground = solidColorBrush;

        //in Closed event, everything is invisible, so use Closing
        Closing += OnClosing;

        ///Load previous Json schema
        TextEditor jsonSchemaArea = FindName("Json_Schema") as TextEditor;
        var schema = Properties.Settings.Default.JsonSchema;
        jsonSchemaArea.Text = schema;
        StackPanel stackPanel = FindName("Json_Schema_Area") as StackPanel;
        stackPanel.Visibility = Properties.Settings.Default.JsonSchemaEditorVisibility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        if(stackPanel.Visibility== Visibility.Visible)
        {
            MenuItem menuItem=FindName("Json_editor_toggle") as MenuItem;
            menuItem.IsChecked = true;
        }
        
        //load fixed Json highlighting
        var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Fixed Json.xshd", UriKind.Relative));
        using(XmlTextReader reader=new XmlTextReader(stream.Stream))
        {
            var xshd=HighlightingLoader.LoadXshd(reader);
            IHighlightingDefinition highlightingDefinition=HighlightingLoader.Load(xshd, HighlightingManager.Instance);
            textEditor.SyntaxHighlighting = highlightingDefinition;
            jsonSchemaArea.SyntaxHighlighting = highlightingDefinition;
        }

        ViewModel.ValidateOnSave = Properties.Settings.Default.ValidateBeforeSaving;

        lastFilePath = Properties.Settings.Default.LastFileOpened;
        if (lastFilePath != null && lastFilePath != "")
        {
            if (File.Exists(lastFilePath))
            {
                LoadFileContents(lastFilePath);
            }
        }

        RoutedCommand command = new RoutedCommand();
        command.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control));
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(command,MenuItem_Click_Save));
        Trace.WriteLine(DataContext);
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openDialog.Filter = "JSON |*.json";
        bool? result = openDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {
            string fileName = openDialog.FileName;
            LoadFileContents(fileName);
        }
    }

    private void LoadFileContents(string fileName)
    {
        TextEditor textEditor = FindName("Text_Area") as TextEditor;
        textEditor.Text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    }

    private void ShowSettings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        settings.Owner = this;
        settings.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

}

Settings.xaml

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JsonEditor"
        x:Class="JsonEditor.Settings"
        xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:JsonEditor" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Settings" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Converters:BrushConverter x:Key="brushConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,199,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Value="{Binding Blackness, Converter={StaticResource brushConverter}}" Maximum="255" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="5"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Settings.xaml.cs with converter

```
namespace JsonEditor
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Settings.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Settings : Window
{
    public Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class BrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = (SolidColorBrush)value;
        return brush.Color.R;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double d = (double)value;
        Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)d, (byte)d, (byte)d));
        return brush;
    }
}
```

}

ViewModel.cs

```
namespace JsonEditor
{
internal class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool validateOnSave=true;
    private Brush avalonEditorBackgroundBlackness=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255,255,255));

    public bool ValidateOnSave
    {
        get { return validateOnSave; } 
        set {  
            validateOnSave = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ValidateOnSave");
        }
    }

    public Brush Blackness
    {
        get { return avalonEditorBackgroundBlackness; }
        set
        {
            avalonEditorBackgroundBlackness = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Blackness");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
}
```

But moving the slider doesn't do anything and no exceptions are thrown. Also background of the editor isn't white on start as expected, but black.

Comment: You have two instances of the ViewModel class, one created in the MainWindow constructor by `ViewModel = new ViewModel(); DataContext = ViewModel;` and one created in the Settings's XAML by `<Window.DataContext><local:ViewModel/></Window.DataContext>`. There should however only be a single instance. So create the Settings Window like `Settings settings = new Settings { Owner = this, DataContext = DataContext };`

Comment: There shouldn't be Brush types in your view model. Instead expose Color or color codes. Exposing the color code or channel code is also more reasonable if you bind to a Slider or manipulate colors in general. Also don't forget to freeze the Brush instance.